# Power Consumption Benchmarks of Different Android Things SoMs?

Tags: raspberry-pi, power-consumption, android-things

I'd be grateful if anyone could publish some results of some (even one is good) Android Things compatible SoMs (System On Modules, [see here](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/developer-kits.html#hardware_platforms)) power consumption benchmark (data for idle, and under load, and also other conditions such as Wi-Fi usage and Bluetooth Low Energy advertising).

All I've found on the internet is [this video in French](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUbryUWvEkY) (a language which I luckily speak) where someone measures energy consumed by a Raspberry Pi 3 running the Android Things Developer Preview of that time, but this unfortunately does not compare it to other boards.

Comment: Could you open a bit what is SoMs? New term for me and may have caused misunderstanding on your subject.

Comment: @mico An SoM is a System On Module. Raspberry Pi 3B and NXP Pico are among the SoMs supported by Android Things. [Here's a list](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/developer-kits.html#hardware_platforms)